# Creating multiple objects to a single object

Tags: jquery

The end result needs to look something like this:

```
Name1: "John"
Name2: "Johnson"
Age: "30"
City: "Atlanta"
State: "GA"
```

I'm trying to push objects into a single object, but what its doing is creating an array with multiple objects that I can't make a single call ( like if I wrapped all the data above in variable newData, I could just call newData[0] and it would return the above ). Currently, I'm trying it like this:

```
var newData = [];
$(data).each(function (i, value) {
    var getTitle = $(value).attr('data-title'); // Returns title
    var getData = $(value).val();
    newData.push({ getTitle : getData });
});
```

This code produces a result like:

```
0:{ getTitle : "John" }
1:{ getTitle : "Johnson" }
2:{ getTitle : "30" }
3:{ getTitle : "Atlanta" }
4:{ getTitle : "State" }
```

So not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you want an array at all, but rather just an object.

```
var newData = {};

$(data).each(function (i, value) {
    var getTitle = $(value).attr('data-title'); // Returns title
    var getData = $(value).val();
    newData[getTitle] = getData;
});
```

Comment: Yeah I tried the object route, but couldn't figure out how to mash it into one

Comment: The syntax on the last line will either update a property of the object if it finds it, or if not, it will add it. The end result should be a single object (`newData`) with your items in it.

Comment: Awesome, this works great. Thanks for saving me more time than I've already spent on it. Will check mark it when i can.